# Azure Storage Javascript library getcontainerclient error

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using @azure/storage-blob library in angular. I get the BlobServiceClient and then call the getContainerClient method and recieve the following error:

*"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL"*

```
var client = new BlobServiceClient(`https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net${sas}`);
let containers = client.listContainers();
const containerClient = client.getContainerClient('containerName');
```

I've search but an unable see if I am doing something wrong..

Comment: Are you able to list containers?

Comment: So, when I run listContainer() method, it runs, but when I try to iterate over the list, it gives me the error "Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL"

Comment: Can you share how your SAS URL looks like? It should start with “?”.

Comment: It does not start with a ?. here is the beginning of it:   sp=r&st=2023-10-05T18:17:12Z&se=2023-10-13T02:17:12Z&spr=https&sv=

Comment: Please try by inserting `?` between the base URL and SAS token. Something like "`https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net?${sas}`".

Comment: I've gotten past my error. It turns our there is a SAS that can be generated on the specific Container, and also a SAS on the Storage Account level. I was generating the SAS on the container and got the error. After I created the SAS on the Storage Account and used the key starting with ?, I no longer get this error.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you still need assistance on this issue or are you good for now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a GetContainerClient operation, you would need a service SAS. This can be created from the Azure storage account portal as shown below:

[image]

Sample code to call the `GetContainerClient` using SAS token is here:

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = "<account name>";
const sas = "<service Shared Access Signature Token>";
const containerName = "<container name>";
const blobName = "<blob name>";

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${sas}`);

async function main() {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
...
...

}
```

If you want to create Service SAS token for a Azure Blob Storage container using javascript, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create-javascript#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob-container) sample code. Hope this helps.